# Detect several objects on single image

Tags: deep-learning

I'm new to deeplearning. I have a picture set and each image can contain several objects (bridge, bed, river, etc.). I want to use deeplearning to detect objects on each image.

For example:
- image 1 contains car and dog
- image 2 contains river, person and boat

I don't have a labeled training dataset. Can I use open image dataset like ImageNet or CIFAR100 to train my model?

Answer (score 0):

If the labels you are looking for are contained in imagenet or cifar100 you can definitely use them for training. Currently sliding windows are used for finding multiple labels in an image. To read up on that approach you can use: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6229.pdf.